# Getting 401 Unauthorized Error In React Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, request, passport.js

So I'm making a request to my database from my react app, after making that request I get all the queried data... And everything works fine. But as soon as I add the **middleware** to the route (this middleware should see if the user is authenticated and logged in) I get a 401 unauthorized status code even after signing in (making POST request to log in) which should enable me to see the data...

**The API routes file, and the GET request from the database, and this code works I get all the data**

```
router.get('/api/v1/get/listing/type/sale', asyncErrorHandle(listingsForSale))
```

**The API routes file, and the GET request from the database, after adding the middleware and it doesn't work**

```
router.get('/api/v1/get/listing/type/sale', isLoggedIn , asyncErrorHandle(listingsForSale))
```

**This is the authentication middleware, I use passport.js**

```
module.exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: 'fail',
            message: 'Access denied, unauthorized'
        })
    }
    next()
}
```

Session implementation and options

```
const sessionOptions = {
secret: 'secretgoeshere',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}

app.use(session(sessionOptions));
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next()
})
```

** The Custom useFetch hook to make requests to the database **

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useFetch = (url, options) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {

        try {

            const fetchData = async() => {

                const res = await fetch(url, options)
                const parsedData = await res.json()

                setData(parsedData)
                setLoading(false)

            }

            fetchData()
        } catch (e) {

            setError(e);
            setLoading(false)

        }

        // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])

    return { data, error, loading }

}

export default useFetch
```

**I tested this same code using Postman and the authentication part with the isLoggedIn middleware works and I get all the data back, but on my react app it doesn't...**

Comment: Where do you save your session data? Can you check if session data (req.user object) populates during passport flow?

Comment: I checked that and it works, that was not the problem...

Comment: I think this problem probably is related to the session because `req.isAuthenticated()` function only checks whether user object is created, can you check the browser cookie session to be sure the session cookie is created in react app?

Comment: Yeah, I can't see the browser cookie session when signing in on the react app, only the localhost session, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please add the code part of your current session implementation  to this post, then I will try to help you.

Comment: I added how I implement the session

Comment: Are you using the client app on a different port? Also, are you using fetch or Axios to send a request to the backend?

Comment: Yes the server is on one port and the react app is on another port, and yes i am using axios to make the fetch request, also on the react app i'm using a custom react hook to make the fetch request as well, i'll add the code to the custom react hook above...

Answer (score 1):

According to your answers in the comment, try to do the following steps:

1. for the backend include this option to `CORS`:

```
const corsOption = {
   credentials: true
}
```

2. add this to the cookie in the express-session:

```
 const sessionOptions = {
secret: 'secretgoeshere',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',  //<===
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}
```

3. for the frontend include the same thing to `fetch`:

```
const option = {
  credentials: 'include'
}
```